# How to convert image of a database table to something I can extract information from?

Tags: sql, mysql

[image: this is the image for your reference]

I was given an image of a sql database model and asked to extract information from it. how do i convert or transcribe the image into something I can do this with?

I don’t know what to try because the database model is an image and not a ddl file.

Comment: That's called an Entity-Relationship Diagram.

Comment: a screenshot…..

Comment: Google "convert er diagram to relational schema". The first hit is for a tool called ERDPlus.

Comment: See this [tutorial](https://www.learndb.com/databases/how-to-convert-er-diagram-to-relational-database)

Comment: Considering that there are 6 tables on the screenshot, you could try to write the sql statements by hand or use your favourite mysql GUI tool to create the tables. I don't think it should take more than 15 minutes in  a GUI tool to replicate the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using this one as a base:
https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3zz3m4gnd

it creates DB tables, ads some dummy data and selects some info from it

MySQL dump:

```sql
CREATE TABLE location (
    location_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    city VARCHAR(50),
    state_province VARCHAR(30),
    postal_code VARCHAR(5),
    country VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE supplier (
    supplier_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    city VARCHAR(50),
    state_province VARCHAR(30),
    postal_code VARCHAR(5),
    country VARCHAR(20),
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle (
    vehicle_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    vehicle_name VARCHAR(10),
    vin VARCHAR(50),
    make VARCHAR(50),
    model VARCHAR(50),
    year INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle_part (
    vehicle_part_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    rfid VARCHAR(255),
    purchase_price DECIMAL(25,5),
    sold_price DECIMAL(25,5),
    vehicle_id INTEGER,
    make VARCHAR(50),
    model VARCHAR(50),
    year INTEGER,
    part_name VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicle(vehicle_id)
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle_part_location (
    vehicle_part_location_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    location_id INTEGER,
    vehicle_part_id INTEGER,
    arrived_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    left_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES location(location_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_part_id) REFERENCES vehicle_part(vehicle_part_id)
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle_part_supplier (
    supplier_id INTEGER,
    vehicle_part_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id, vehicle_part_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_part_id) REFERENCES vehicle_part(vehicle_part_id)
);

-- Insert corrected sample data into 'location'
INSERT INTO location (location_id, city, state_province, postal_code, country) VALUES
(1, 'Edinburgh', 'Scotland', 'EH11B', 'UK'),
(2, 'Glasgow', 'Scotland', 'G11XW', 'UK');

-- Insert corrected sample data into 'supplier'
INSERT INTO supplier (supplier_id, city, state_province, postal_code, country, name) VALUES
(1, 'Birmingham', 'England', 'B11TT', 'UK', 'AutoParts Ltd'),
(2, 'Leeds', 'England', 'LS11B', 'UK', 'CarParts Co');
-- Insert sample data into 'vehicle'
INSERT INTO vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, vin, make, model, year) VALUES
(1, 'EcoCar', '1HGCM82633A004352', 'Toyota', 'Prius', 2020),
(2, 'FamilyCar', '1HGCM82633A004353', 'Honda', 'Civic', 2021);

-- Insert sample data into 'vehicle_part'
INSERT INTO vehicle_part (vehicle_part_id, rfid, purchase_price, sold_price, vehicle_id, make, model, year, part_name) VALUES
(1, 'RFID123456', 100.00, 150.00, 1, 'Toyota', 'Prius', 2020, 'Battery'),
(2, 'RFID123457', 50.00, 75.00, 2, 'Honda', 'Civic', 2021, 'Air Filter');

-- Insert sample data into 'vehicle_part_location'
INSERT INTO vehicle_part_location (vehicle_part_location_id, location_id, vehicle_part_id, arrived_timestamp, left_timestamp) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2024-01-01 10:00:00', NULL),
(2, 2, 2, '2024-01-02 10:00:00', '2024-01-03 15:00:00');

-- Insert sample data into 'vehicle_part_supplier'
INSERT INTO vehicle_part_supplier (supplier_id, vehicle_part_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2);

SELECT vp.part_name, l.city, l.state_province
FROM vehicle_part vp
JOIN vehicle_part_location vpl ON vp.vehicle_part_id = vpl.vehicle_part_id
JOIN location l ON vpl.location_id = l.location_id;


SELECT YEAR(vp.year) AS year, SUM(vp.sold_price) AS total_sales
FROM vehicle_part vp
GROUP BY YEAR(vp.year);

SELECT vp.part_name, l.city
FROM vehicle_part vp
JOIN vehicle_part_location vpl ON vp.vehicle_part_id = vpl.vehicle_part_id
JOIN location l ON vpl.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE vpl.left_timestamp IS NULL;


SELECT s.name, s.city, vp.part_name
FROM supplier s
JOIN vehicle_part_supplier vps ON s.supplier_id = vps.supplier_id
JOIN vehicle_part vp ON vps.vehicle_part_id = vp.vehicle_part_id
WHERE vp.part_name = 'Battery';

SELECT s.name, s.city, vp.part_name
FROM supplier s
JOIN vehicle_part_supplier vps ON s.supplier_id = vps.supplier_id
JOIN vehicle_part vp ON vps.vehicle_part_id = vp.vehicle_part_id
WHERE vp.part_name = 'Battery';

SELECT vp.part_name, COUNT(*) AS total_parts, SUM(vp.purchase_price) AS total_cost
FROM vehicle_part vp
GROUP BY vp.part_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create Tables and provides Primary key and Unique key as per model image and then you can get easily .
Create Table [dbo].[location](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) location_id NOT NULL,

)
and create all and then work out .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).